# How do I detect whether a representation is (or is not) the adjoint representation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $(\mathfrak{g},[\cdot,\cdot])$ be a Lie algebra. There is a God-given representation of $\mathfrak{g}$, namely, the adjoint representation $\operatorname{ad} : \mathfrak{g} \to \operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$ given by $x \mapsto [x,{-}]$. A standard treatment of representation theory motivates the adjoint representation via the assumption that representations may be hard to find, but, nevertheless, there is always one which is associated to $\mathfrak{g}$. This is what I understand to be the meaning of "canonical" in this context.

I want to turn this treatment on its head (if this is obvious, trivial, silly, or well-known, I apologise in advance—I'm not a representation theorist).

With $(\mathfrak{g}, [\cdot, \cdot])$ still denoting our Lie algebra, let $\rho : \mathfrak{g} \to \operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$ be a representation.

> How do I *detect* whether $\rho$ is (or is not) the adjoint representation?

I would be very intrigued if there is a cohomological measure or some powerful general machinery for checking this. If further clarification is required, or my question is not clear, please let me know :-)

**Edit:** In light of @LSpice's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416420/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-representation-is-or-is-not-the-adjoint-representati#comment1068372_416420), here is my motivation: I can prove a result *for the adjoint representation*, and I want to prove this result for more general representations. Therefore, I want to understand the *deviation* of a given representation $\rho$ from the adjoint representation, or the obstruction to a representation being the adjoint representation. (These statements need to be taken in a "moral spirit".)

Comment: Of course you don't want the answer "if and only if $\rho(X) = \operatorname{ad}(X)$ for all $X$", but—pardon my saying—why not?  Since the adjoint representation is there, what is the advantage of not comparing directly to it?  Or is your question more like:  what are some pleasant properties of the adjoint representation? \\ Do you want an answer for general $\mathfrak g$, or are you interested in specific families of $\mathfrak g$?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question with some clarification, I hope this is clearer :-)

Comment: Well if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple then you have the whole theory of weights, but maybe you are not interested in that case?

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  As @SamHopkins [says](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416420/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-representation-is-or-is-not-the-adjoint-representati#comment1068374_416420), probably the most satisfactory answers will be in the case where $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple, and/or when $\mathfrak g$ is nilpotent.  Are you interested only in results for general $\mathfrak g$, or are results for specific $\mathfrak g$ of interest?  Maybe you could say what your result is, to give some guidance regarding reasonable answers.

Comment: Maybe what the OP wants to know is how to tell whether a given representation $\rho$ is *isomorphic to* the adjoint representation.  For example, for a simple Lie algebra, where $\mathrm{Der}({\frak g}) = {\frak g}$, this easy because we know all of the automorphisms of $\frak g$.  At the other extreme, when $\frak g$ is abelian,  $\rho$ could be any linear map into an abelian subalgebra of $\mathrm{Der}({\frak g}) = \mathrm{End}({\frak g})$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you for this comment, I apologise for the lack of clarity in my question (the problem remains rather opaque). Nevertheless, here's an attempt to improve the clarity of the question: I have some finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and I know only this--I have a vector space with a Lie bracket. At present, that is all I can say about the structure of $\mathfrak{g}$, but I will try to discover more.

Comment: @RobertBryant Now, I'm consider the space of maps $\rho : \mathfrak{g} \to \text{Der}(\mathfrak{g})$ which may be any representation. I would like to know when I can assert that there exists an $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\rho(y) = [x,y]$. I hope this makes sense :-)

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you for your comment. Do the above two comments give additional clarity?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your comment. I apologise for the growing number of comments, I'm not sure if tagging multiple people in one comment works.

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1068595) unfortunately does not seem to make sense; $\rho(y)$ as written should be an element of $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak g)$, so it can't be an element of $\mathfrak g$ (except *via* an implicit identification).  You can ask of a map $\rho : \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g$ whether $\rho$ equals $\operatorname{ad}(x)$ for some $x \in \mathfrak g$, or of a map $\rho : \mathfrak g \to \operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak g)$ whether $\rho$ equals $\operatorname{ad}$; do you mean one of them?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you helping me clarify this, I really appreciate your efforts. I believe that I'm asking the first question, whether $\rho : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ equals $\text{ad}(x)$ for some $x \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: OK.  [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416420/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-representation-is-or-is-not-the-adjoint-representati#comment1068669_416420) is not what your question asks, and seems to me unlikely to admit a particularly exciting answer.  (As @RobertBryant [observes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416420/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-representation-is-or-is-not-the-adjoint-representati#comment1068455_416420), for example, it could be that all derivations are of this form.)  I think you might want to consider trying this question again after thinking what and why you are asking.

Comment: Your $\rho\colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is assumed to be a derivation of $\mathfrak{g}$, right? If so, then what you are asking is: how do we detect whether $\rho$ is an *inner derivation*?